# Spring Boot - What Annotations Are Needed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I am new to Spring Boot and I was just wondering if I need all annotations on my main method that I currently have
Here they are

```
    @Import(ServiceConfiguration.class)
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.myproject.rest",})
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.myproject.dao.jpa"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.myproject.domain.jpa")
```

The class ServiceConfiguration.class has the following annotations

```
    @Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({SlackServiceProperties.class})
```

My database objects have the @Entity annotation, my rest classes have the @RestController annotation and my service classes have the @Component annotation

Just wondering are they all needed or can I exclude any of these annotations?

Thanks

Comment: I'm also new to Spring Boot, but I think what you have probably looks OK.  Here is the start of the @SpringBootAppliaction annotation documentation -  http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html

Comment: Without seeing the actual packages your application class is in it is hard to tell if you need more or less annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you structure your code like so:

```
com.myproject
 - Application.java
com.myproject.configuration
 - ServiceConfiguration.java
 - OtherConfiguration.java
com.myproject.dao.jpa
 - .. your repositories..
com.myproject.domain.jpa
 - .. your @Entity classes...
```

You **ONLY** need to annotate your Application class with `@SpringBootApplication`.

All your `@Configuration`, repositories, other `@Component` and `@Service` classes will be auto scanned and configured by Spring Boot. That means you **DON'T** need to manually `@Import` configurations, you don't need `@EnableJpaRepositories` or `@EntityScan`.

All you need for Spring Boot to configure JPA is to include the JPA starter:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

You can follow this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

You will see that it requires minimal annotations.

Answer (score 3):

If your main method is located in a top-level package, then all you need is:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
```

It will automatically scan your sources recursively and pick up any @`Bean`'s, `@Component`'s or `@Configuration`'s

Spring Data JPA will also automatically be configured if you're using this starter:

```
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume it may depend on what you need, as I have not used a few of those in your example. I am not too familiar with all of Spring's "magic" when it comes to behind-the-scenes work it does with annotations. I have a perfectly functioning Spring Boot app with only

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
```

In order,

**@SpringBootApplication** is Spring's way of identifying that this application is from Spring Boot (one consequence, for example, is that there is no web.xml file).

**@Configuration** tells Spring to look for .properties files on your src path. Here, for example, you can define an "application.properties" file to define your datasource (database information for Spring to use).

**@Component** tells Spring to look for "Components" when it starts up the application. Pretty much @Controllers, @Service, etc. that may be found throughout your application.

For more accurate and in-depth explanations for many of Spring's annotations, may I direct you to:

http://www.techferry.com/articles/spring-annotations.html 
and
https://dzone.com/refcardz/spring-annotations

These both have excellent descriptions and examples for the annotations.

**Edit:** @Configuration and @ComponentScan are included in @SpringBootApplication, as Strelok has pointed out in the comments.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You only need `@SpringBootApplication`, it's a meta annotation that implies all the others.

Comment: Strelok, you are correct. My application still functions the same without them. I've edited my answer to acknowledge this.